# how to Iterate over data frame in shiny app

Tags: r, for-loop, shiny

I am trying to iterate over a data frame (***values$df***) in order to apply some functions per row and then bind the outputs in another data frame (***cot$tarifas***). I used a for loop and although there is no error showing on the screen, there is no data available in the resulted data frame (***cot$tarifas***) and I don't understand why.

I post here an extract of the code where I think the error is occurring but for a reproducible example I recommend you to download the files that are in [this folder](https://1drv.ms/u/s!AvkvtefHy3c4yhCqncdN8AuP6zdX?e=Emkkr0). You should change the path in the code to the path where you save the files and load to the app the file named "*file_to_upload*". I do not post the entire code here because it is a bit long

```
  cot <- reactiveValues()
  observe({
    cot$tarifas <- tibble(
      Row = numeric(0)) %>%
      mutate("Fondo" = "", "Region"= "", "Estado"="",
             "Cultivo"= "", "Infraestructura"= "", "Riesgos"= "","Unidad de Riesgo"="",
             "Subramo" = "", "Nivel de S.A." = numeric(0), "Deducible" = "", "Part. Perdida" = "", "Tarifa" = numeric(0))
  })
  
  proxyTable2 <- DT::dataTableProxy("tarifas")
  
  output$envio <- renderDT({
    DT::datatable(cot$tarifas[,-1],
                  rownames = FALSE,
                  escape   = FALSE)
  })
  myTable2 <- isolate(cot$tarifas)
  # I BELIEVE THERE IS SOMETHING WRONG IN THE FOLLOWING REACTIVE
  eventReactive(input$continue,{
    for (j in 1:dim(values$df)[1]) {
      cotizacion <- busca_folios(fondo_edo(), cultivos(),values$df$Fondo[j], values$df$Region[j],values$df$Cultivo[j],
                             values$df$`Sistema de produccion`[j], values$df$`Seguro agricultura protegida`[j],
                             values$df$`Unidad de riesgo`[j], values$df$Riesgos[j], values$df$Deducible[j],
                             values$df$`Participacion a perdida`[j])
      
      if(dim(cotizacion)[1] > 0){
        myTable2 <- bind_rows(myTable2, tibble(Row = rep(1,3)) %>%
                                add_column(cotizacion))
      }else{
        cotizacion2 <- calculo(fondo_edo(),cultivos(),values$df[j,1],values$df$Region[j], values$df$Cultivo[j],
                          values$df$`Sistema de produccion`[j], values$df$`Seguro agricultura protegida`[j],
                          values$df$`Unidad de riesgo`[j], ordena_riesgos(values$df$Riesgos[j]),
                          separa_vector(values$df$Deducibles[j]), separa_vector(values$df$PPs[j]), values$df$Fondo[j])
        
        myTable2 <- bind_rows(myTable2, tibble(Row = rep(1,3)) %>%
                                add_column(cotizacion2))
      }
    }
    replaceData(proxyTable2, myTable2, resetPaging = FALSE)
    cot$tarifas <- myTable2
  })
```

#### Expexted output

[image: expected output]

Thank you very much for your help, I really appreciate it

Comment: You have numerous issues.  You are nesting reactives inside reactives.  That does not make any sense.  Also, you are try to use it within the for loop before the reactive is complete.  Next, your functions seem to have issues.  Please ensure that they work independently outside of shiny.  Please ensure that you post an [MRE](https://stackoverflow.com/help/minimal-reproducible-example) so that someone can help you.

Comment: Hi @YBS, thank you for your comment. You are right about the nested reactive, it doesn't make sense. I updated the code so that there is no reactives inside reactives but that was not the problem. Second, my functions work fine outside of shiny, there is no problem with them, that's how I got the expected output table ;). So the problem is that the values of col$tarifas are not being replaced with the new data and I don't understand why. The issue must be in the for loop but I don't know where

Comment: I suggest changing `myTable2 <- bind_rows(myTable2, tibble(Row = rep(1,3)) %>% add_column(cotizacion))`  to n <- nrow(cotizacion)
myTable2 <- bind_rows(myTable2, tibble(Row = rep(1,n)) %>% add_column(cotizacion))

Comment: @YBS thanks so much for your time and help. I managed to solve my issue :)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Solved it! I was making things way more complicated than needed. I changed the above code for the following

```
output$envio <- renderDT({
    myTable2 <- data.frame()
    for (j in 1:dim(values$df)[1]) {
      cotizacion <- busca_folios(fondo_edo(), cultivos(),values$df$Fondo[j], values$df$Region[j],values$df$Cultivo[j],
                                 values$df$`Sistema de produccion`[j], values$df$`Seguro agricultura protegida`[j],
                                 values$df$`Unidad de riesgo`[j], values$df$Riesgos[j], values$df$Deducible[j],
                                 values$df$`Participacion a perdida`[j])
      
      if(dim(cotizacion)[1] > 0){
        myTable2 <- rbind(myTable2, cotizacion)
      }else{
        cotizacion2 <- calculo(fondo_edo(),cultivos(),values$df[j,1],values$df$Region[j], values$df$Cultivo[j],
                               values$df$`Sistema de produccion`[j], values$df$`Seguro agricultura protegida`[j],
                               values$df$`Unidad de riesgo`[j], ordena_riesgos(values$df$Riesgos[j]),
                               separa_vector(values$df$Deducibles[j]), separa_vector(values$df$PPs[j]), values$df$Fondo[j])
        
        myTable2 <- rbind(myTable2, cotizacion2)
      }
    }
    return(DT::datatable(myTable2 ))
  })
```